# Tabindex not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a login page which contains 2 input fields & a submit button. I have set the page to auto focus the username input field when the page load with `$("#username").select()`.

However, when I press down "tab" key on keyboard, instead of jump to the password field, it jump to the browser address field. I tried to solve it by putting username field with tabindex = 1 and password fiel with tabindex = 2. But the situation still the same.

I notice that if I manually mouse click on the username field or refresh the page, it will jump to password field when "tab" key is pressed.

So, how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use **.focus()** instead of .select()

```
$("#username").focus();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8a4v/)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `$("#username").focus()` before. I'm not sure selecting an element changes the tabindex. I'm pretty sure focus does.

BTW, there was some bugs on IE, forcing you to enclose select and focus functions into a setTimeout, like that :

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#username").select()}, 1);
```